How to prevent ggplot2 from prioritizing ordering alphabetically?
I can't seem to get this plot to show the Weight column ordered, it prioritizes ordering the Breed column alphabetically even though I made the Weight a categorical column and set ordered to True, I don't know what to do... When I print the dataframe before plotting, it orders the dataframe by the Weight value.
sorted_weight = traits_n_weights.sort_values(by=["Weight"])

top_weight = sorted_weight.head(70)
bins = sorted(top_weight["Weight"].unique())

top_weight = top_weight.assign(
    Weight=pd.Categorical(top_weight["Weight"], categories=bins, ordered=True),
) 

plot = ggplot(top_weight, aes(x="factor(Weight)", y="Breed")) + geom_point() + labs(y="")

plot

The Weight column contains float values, the Breed contains string values. I have tried removing the factor part of x="factor(Weight)", can someone help me?
These are the imports of the code
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *


Please add some data to your post. You can use the dput() function of R to output code that others can use to reproduce your data frame. Run either dput(top_weight) or, if the data frame is large, dput(head(top_weight, 20)) and add the output to your questions.

If you want to make a plot where Breed is ordered according to Weight then one option would be to make Breed a categorical (instead of Weight) and reorder the categories according to Weight.
Using a minimal reproducible example based on mtcars:
from plotnine.data import mtcars
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

traits_n_weights = mtcars[["name", "wt"]].copy()
traits_n_weights.columns = ["Breed", "Weight"]

top_weight = traits_n_weights.sort_values(by=["Weight"]).head(10)

# Make Breed a categorical and reorder accoding to Weight
top_weight["Breed"] = top_weight["Breed"].astype("category").cat.reorder_categories(
    top_weight.set_index("Breed").index
)

plot = (ggplot(top_weight, aes(x="Weight", y="Breed")) + 
    geom_point() + 
    labs(y=""))

plot



Instead of using factor, plotnine has another internal function reorder that changes the order of first variable based on values of the second.
In your case, that would be
ggplot(top_weight, aes(x="Weight", y="reorder(Breed, Weight)"))

See aes() notes section for more.
